# Why can I not copy win console application to linux ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, visual-studio

I am running a win 10 host and a VMware with Linux Ubunto 22.04 LTS.

I have created a .Net6.0 helloWorld console application and published it as a self-contained app.

I then tried to copy&paste it from host to VM but it is not possible. It works with a textfile but not my build. Files app is crashing on Linux when attempting this.

I have also failed when I tried:
zip it in both 7s and tar
publish for linux-arm, linux-x64 and win-x64

I want to know what the issue is.

Comment: Windows binaries will not run on Linux.  If you have the source code, you need to rebuild on Linux.  If it is C#, rebuild in mono

Comment: Just to clarify: it's the **copying** that crashes the file explorer? You may want to emphasize it (use the [edit] button). I'm guessing other users are confused and think you're trying to run a Windows app on Linux.

Comment: Good point, I have published it as a self-contained application compiled for Linux. The file is fine for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

The issue was that the file exceeded 65 mb in size which was the max allowed for copying.

A workaround is to mount a shared directory and pass the files through that way.